# Rendering Rails partial form in another partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models called project and test. A project has many tests.

In the **index.html.erb** of tests, I have:

```
<%= render @tests %>
```

So I therefore have a file called **_test.html.erb**, and in it I have:

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

I then have a filed called **_form.html.erb** with:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.tests.build]) do |f| %>
        <p>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

But I get an exception:

> undefined method `tests' for nil:NilClass

So `@project` is apparently nil. I understand my set up is a bit strange, so I'm not sure how I would refactor this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are accessible from any level of rendering.
You can render 100 partials inside each other and you would still have access to those same ivars.

The problem looks like you aren't actually setting @project anywhere.
You probably are looking for "test.project" in your form.

Comment: Where should I be setting @project?

Comment: Ah ok the issue was that I was supposed to be setting @project in my tests controller index method: `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render @tests, project: @project %>
```

Then

```
<%= render 'form', project: project %>
```

The idea is to pass in the `@project` instance variable as a local variable.

Comment: @project is nil for some reason in my tests index.html.erb.

Answer (score -1):

Are both partials in the same view?

You will also have to pass the @project object to the partial and every partial that uses @project.

Example:

```
<%= render @tests, project: @project %>
```

Comment: Rendering an instance variable as a plural will automatically loop the array and render the individual partial for each item in the array. So in this case, `_test.html.erb` will be rendered for each `test` in `@tests`